# Partial Fraction of Trigonometric Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

How do I split a trig function as the sum of two quantities?

For example, I can see easily that $\frac{5x+3}{x(x+1)}$ can be solved making it equal to $\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x+1}$, solving for $A$ and $B$. But what if we have something like 
\begin{equation*}
\cfrac{1}{1-\cos^2(x)}
\end{equation*}

I found that I can simply describe the denominator here in terms of the product of two quantities by factoring out $\cos(x)$ 
\begin{align*}
\cfrac{1}{1-\cos^2(x)}=&\cfrac{1}{\cos (x)(cos(x)-\frac{1}{cos(x)})} = \cfrac{A}{\cos(x)}+\cfrac{B}{\cos(x)-\frac{1}{\cos(x)}} \\ 
=& A(\cos(x)-\frac{1}{\cos(x)})+B(\cos(x))=1 \biggr\vert_{x=2\pi} \\
B =& 1
\\ A =& 0 \\
\\ \implies& \cfrac{1}{1-\cos^2(x)} = 0 + \cfrac{1}{\cos(x)-\frac{1}{\cos(x)}}
\end{align*}

But this doesn't look right. Can trigonometric equations not be split the way algebraic expressions can? Or is this a special case?

Comment: $1-\cos^2 x = (1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)$.

Comment: Holy hell how did I not notice that

I'm ashamed lmao

Comment: Ok so working with that, I still have an issue where I end up dividing by 0 after cancelling out either A or B.

Answer (score 1):

It can sometimes be useful to rewrite trigonometric expressions in terms of their coordinate equivalents on the unit circle.  A dictionary:\begin{align*}
\cos \theta &\leftrightarrow x  \\
\sin \theta &\leftrightarrow y  \\
\tan \theta &\leftrightarrow y/x  \\
\end{align*}
and so on.  For your particular example, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-\cos^2 \theta} &\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{1-x^2}  \\
&= \frac{1}{1-x^2}  \\
&= \frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)}  \\
&= \frac{1/2}{x+1} + \frac{-1/2}{x-1}  \\
&\leftrightarrow \frac{1/2}{1 + \cos x} + \frac{1/2}{1 - \cos x}\text{.}
\end{align*}
(In your particular problem, use caution that you do not become confused by two different uses of "$x$".  For instance, use $u$ and $v$, instead.)
Note that this form sometimes makes it easier for our "algebra eyes" to more readily see patterns.

However, there is a down side: we are less likely to notice trigonometric identities that can help.  In this case,
$$  \frac{1}{1-\cos^2 x} = \frac{1}{\sin^2 x} = \csc^2 x  \text{.}  $$
(Whether this is help or is working backwards through your prior work depends on context that has not been presented as part of the Question.)

Maybe you are also seeking help solving for the coefficients in the partial fraction decomposition.  From
$$  \frac{1}{1-\cos^2 \theta} = \frac{A}{1 + \cos x} + \frac{B}{1 - \cos x} = \frac{A(1 - \cos x) +B(1 + \cos x)}{(1+ \cos x)(1 - \cos x)}  = \frac{(A+B)+ (-A+B)\cos x}{1 - \cos^2 x}  \text{,}  $$
we have $A+B = 1$ and $-A+B = 0$.  Adding these, $2B = 1+0$ so $B = 1/2$ and subtracting these, $2A = 1-0$ so $A = 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you write
$$\frac{1}{1-\cos^2 x} = \frac{A}{1-\cos x}+\frac{B}{1+\cos x} = \frac{A+B+(B-A)\cos x}{1-\cos^2 x},$$
comparing numerators shows that $A+B=1$ and $B-A=0$, so that $A = B = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: "$(B-A)$" should be "$(A-B)$".